# Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'StorageAccountKey' when trying to create a Blobcontainer

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to create a container inside a Storage Account using the following statements:

```
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $rg_bk -Location $Region -Tag @{CompanyName = $Customer_Name }
$StorageAccountName = "bacpacssa$(Get-Random)"
New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rg_bk -Name $StorageAccountName -Location $Region -SkuName Standard_GRS -Tag @{CompanyName = $Customer_Name } -Kind BlobStorage -AccessTier Cool
$storageKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $rg_bk -Name $StorageAccountName).Value 
$StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey 
$ContainerName = "databasesbacpac$(Get-Random)"
New-AzStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Context $StorageContext -Permission Off
```

but I am also getting the following error

```
New-AzStorageContext : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'StorageAccountKey'. Specified method is not supported.
```

Comment: this `'System.Object[]'` means you have a collection, not a single object. try checking the $Var to see what it contains ... and then try iterating thru it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```bsh
$storageKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $rg_bk -Name $StorageAccountName).Value
```

Returns two objects, so you get the value for each of them in an array. Your next cmdlet ([`New-AzStorageContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-4.7.0)) requires one value for `-StorageAccountKey` value.

If you just want to use the first one, you could fix it like this.

```bsh
$storageKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $rg_bk -Name $StorageAccountName)[0].Value
```

This means you will only then use the value from `key1`. If you want to use key2, you can change it to `[1]`.